# Adding an Array of labels to a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add an array of labels to a panel in my Form.
I chose a label because I could set colors for the text.
If there is a better way, please let me know.

The code below runs fine but will only display one label.
I set a breakpoint and looked at the array before adding and all the 
elements are there.

However, only one label actually shows up on the Panel.

Here's the code.

```
        int y = 0;
        int index = 0;

        Label[] labels = new Label[10];

        //Add Spareboard Employees to Spare List
        foreach (Employee employee in EmployeeList)
        {
                labels[index] = new Label();

                labels[index].Text = employee.Name;

                labels[index].ForeColor = Color.Red;

                labels[index].Location = new Point(0, y);

                y = y + 10;
                ++index;
        }

        // Add the Label control to the form.
        SparePanel.Controls.AddRange(labels);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default size of the label is too big and each label's bottom is covering up the top of the label below it.  You should add something like this:

```
labels[index].Size = new Size(50, 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
    Label[] labels = new Label[10];
```

needs to be

```
    Control[] labels = new Control[10];
```

Comment: Same thing happens if I define it as a control

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to implement the IEnumerable Interface and IEnumerate.Compare() method too, in order to iterate a foreach loop over your Employee object.

```
public class Employee : IEnumerator
{

//Implement IEnumerate method here


}
```

I'm not that experienced though so don't take my word for it! I would put more detailed code but I don't have it to hand.

Comment: I took the foreach loop out and just tested a simple case.
I get the same issue of only one showing up.

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                labels[index] = new Label();

                labels[index].Text = "Test";

                labels[index].ForeColor = Color.Red;

                labels[index].Location = new Point(0, y);

                y = y + 10;
                ++index;
            }

Comment: MSDN says the following, may well apply to you:

Notes to Inheritors:
When overriding AddRange in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's AddRange method to ensure that the controls are added to the collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.addrange.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (which you were also looking for) is to draw the strings directly on the UI without adding controls.  Do it during the paint event of the panel.

```
private void SparePanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   using (SolidBrush empBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
   {
      int y = 0;
      foreach (Employee employee in EmployeeList)
      {
         e.Graphics.DrawString(employee.Name, ((Panel)sender).Font, empBrush, 0, y);
         y += 10;
      }
   }
}
```